# How to display images in webpage through a list of urls of images in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, image-rendering

I have URL's of images stored in a List in python.

How should I display those images on my web page using Django.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
# HTML file
# If your list is 'urls'
{% for url in urls %}
    <img src="{{ url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**

From your comment, I got your Urls list, you should save your list like this:

```
['toi.cricbuzz.com/scripts/images/toi-logo.gif', 'toi.cricbuzz.com/scripts/images/cb-logo.png', 'img.cricketcb.com/i/gallery/fth/140x75/images/2015/oct/2/…', 'img.cricketcb.com/i/gallery/fth/140x75/images/2015/oct/1/…', 'img.cricketcb.com/i/gallery/fth/140x75/images/2015/sep/27/…', 'img.cricketcb.com/i/gallery/fth/140x75/images/2015/sep/17/…']
```

You can test this list above in your template, it should display images.

Comment: it would be endfor not endif

Comment: @gaurav_kamble thanks, I edited.

Comment: I tried using this, but I am getting TypeError : unhashable type: 'dict' .

Comment: @arpitjain2402 show your list of urls please.

Comment: The list gets changes on every request : PFB the list for one request :  ['http://toi.cricbuzz.com/scripts/images/toi-logo.gif', 'http://toi.cricbuzz.com/scripts/images/cb-logo.png', 'http://img.cricketcb.com/i/gallery/fth/140x75/images/2015/oct/2/prv_63c85_1443793619.jpg', 'http://img.cricketcb.com/i/gallery/fth/140x75/images/2015/oct/1/prv_aa02f_1443711267.jpg', 'http://img.cricketcb.com/i/gallery/fth/140x75/images/2015/sep/27/prv_6b851_1443359583.jpg', 'http://img.cricketcb.com/i/gallery/fth/140x75/images/2015/sep/17/prv_3a2e7_1442542041.jpg', ]

Comment: I don't know why the elements are separated with ';' and every url redirects to a web page, not an image.

Comment: I agree. I need to display all the image through these image URLs on one single web page . Any suggestions for that .

Comment: @arpitjain2402 I edited the answer